# Laravel stores images with permission 600

Tags: laravel, permissions, upload, laravel-5.4, shared-hosting

I have a Laravel5.4 project on a shared-host.

When I upload an image from my project admin panel, it store in my host with permission 600 instead 644 .

My store function:

```
public function store(PosterRequest $request)
{
    $poster = Poster::create($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $filename = $request->file('image')->store('photos', ['disk' => 'upload']);
        $poster->update(['image' => $filename]);
    }

    $poster->categories()->attach($request->categories);

    return redirect(route('posters.edit', ['id' => $poster->id]));
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions of the storage directory and its contents to what you need, and any future files should take the same permissions.

Open a terminal and navigate to your application.

Run
`chmod -R 644 /storage`

Comment: 1- I told that I am using shared-hosting and I have not access to terminal.
2- I want to store images with default permission 644 .

Comment: Try go to cpanel go to file manager and right click files/folder then change permission.

Comment: As Jesus says, it can be done in the cpanel. With these new permissions, all subsequent uploads should have the same permissions as what you set from now.

Comment: My upload folder permission was 755 from first.

Comment: Change it to 644, make another upload and see what it is. Unfortunately cpanel doesn't allow you to recursively set permissions to all files contained within the folder. You'd need terminal access for that. But having changed the folder permissions itself the new files should follow.

Comment: Failed, look at that I do upload from my laravel project.

Comment: Try Laravel's MakeDirectory method to create a directory with the permissions you want, and try and upload it to there. Remember to set the $recursive value to true. Let me know if this works or not. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L436